# low resolution of preview-latex in emacs in latex mode on mac with retina display

Tags: emacs, retina-display, retina, auctex

if I am running latex preview within emacs on mac with retina display, unfortunately I am not getting the proper resolution but rather some fuzzy looking (I guess half the resolution) images. Still, the size of the image is correct.

[Skreenshot showing that text has a razor sharp resolution whilst the preview-latex is quite blurry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J507v.png)

Might be a good info: I am running OSX Catalina and Emacs which I installed through

```
brew tap railwaycat/emacsmacport
brew cask install emacs-mac
```

PS: As I am confused by the different available emacs for mac. Using `brew tap railwaycat/emacsmacport` I am using the emacs distribution from [emacsformacosx](https://emacsformacosx.com)